# Jenkins - Plugin Manager Configuration

Tags: jenkins, plugins

I'm new to Jenkins and I'm not sure about what info should in  --> Server "[   ]"
Should i paste the Jenkins url ?, my computer ip ?, ipv4, ipv6?
I'm getting an error probably because that configuration is not ok.

I try to paste url Jenkins localhost info but I'm getting error.

Comment: Which server are you referring to? I don't remember having to set a server url in the plugin manager.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you mean on `/pluginManager/advanced`, "Manage Jenkins > Manage Plugins > Advanced. HTTP Proxy Configuration | Server".

If you can click on "Check Now" on the Plugins page it it updates the plugins list, then you don't need to do anything.

Assuming you are behind a firewall, enter a [Proxy Configuration](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/JenkinsBehindProxy) (1) value. It can be an IP address, a hostname or a [PAC file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config). Port is necessary, other fields optional as needed.
[image: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/attachments/72777849/95813638.png]]

After adding a value, click on the "Advanced" button; there is a Validate Proxy option. Make sure the "Server" value omits the "http://", but the "Test URL" includes the full url (it can be any external url you choose; eg: https://google.com or https://github.com).

The Server (?) help option also notes:

> If your Jenkins server sits behind a firewall and does not have the
> direct access to the internet, and if your server JVM is not
> configured appropriately (See [JDK networking properties](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html) for more
> details) to enable internet connection, you can specify the HTTP proxy
> server name in this field to allow Jenkins to install plugins on
> behalf of you. Note that Jenkins uses HTTPS to communicate with the
> update center to download plugins.
>
> Leaving this field empty means
> Jenkins will try to connect to the internet directly.
>
> If you are unsure about the value, check the browser proxy
> configuration.

---

Note: There is a field under the `configure` "Manage Jenkins > Configure System" page for:
Jenkins Location
Jenkins URL "[     ]"

That would be your localhost name / IP if necessary

> This value is used to let Jenkins know how to refer to itsel

(1) No idea why this wiki page was not migrated to the new wiki.